# Can't load kernel binary:Invalid SDK hash

Tags: hash, sdk, kernel

I want to run flutter web after write flutter channel beta it replies: Can't load kernel binary:Invalid SDK hash, do you know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

- locate flutter installation folder
- delete flutter/bin/cache

-run flutter doctor